# Creating " if not an integer" if statement condition (C++)

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, do-while

Working on an assignment where the user enters some data in a certain format (ex. "Ernest Hemingway, 9") and then its put that information in a table.

I have to take into account for errors in user input. Not putting a comma, putting too many commas, and check that the data after the "," is a valid integer.

ex.
Ernest Hemingway 9

Error: No comma in string.

Ernest, Hemingway, 9

Error: Too many commas in input.

Ernest Hemingway, nine      (input i am having trouble with)

Error: Comma not followed by an integer.

Ernest Hemingway, 9

Data string: Ernest Hemingway
Data integer: 9

below is my current code

```
    int commaCount = 0; // keeps track of commas in users input
    int currentIndex = 0; // creating variable to create elements in the vectors

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a data point (-1 to stop input) :" << endl;
        getline(cin, userInput);

        if (userInput == "-1") { break; } // meant to break out of loop if the user inputs "-1" on their first attempt

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
            if (userInput.at(i) == ',') {
                commaCount++;
            }
        }

        if (commaCount == 0) {
            cout << "Error: No comma in string." << endl;
        }

        else if (commaCount > 1) {
            cout << "Error: Too many commas in input." << endl;
        }

        //else if ( second half of string != a POSITIVE int) "If entry after the comma is not an integer"

        else {
        breakPoint = userInput.find(',');

        listOfAuthors.push_back(userInput.substr(0, breakPoint));
        novelsPerAuthor.push_back(stoi(userInput.substr(breakPoint + 1, userInput.length() - breakPoint + 1)));


        cout << "Data string: " << listOfAuthors.at(currentIndex) << endl;
        cout << "Data integer: " << novelsPerAuthor.at(currentIndex) << endl;
        currentIndex++;

        }

        commaCount = 0; // resets comma count between entries

        cout << " " << endl;
    } while (userInput != "-1"); //exits user input loop if "-1" is inputed
```

below is my code for how i separate the string and convert the second half into an int if it helps provide context for the code above.

```
breakPoint = userInput.find(',');

        listOfAuthors.push_back(userInput.substr(0, breakPoint));
        novelsPerAuthor.push_back(stoi(userInput.substr(breakPoint + 1, userInput.length() - breakPoint + 1)));
```

Is there a way to write a condition that states something along the lines if userInput.substr(breakPoint + 1, userInput.length() - breakPoint + 1)) does not equal a positive integer, the program will print "Error: Comma not followed by an integer."

Comment: The simplest way would be to write a function isAPositiveInteger, and then call that function from your if statement, `if (!isAPositiveInteger(userInput.substr(breakPoint + 1, userInput.length() - breakPoint + 1))) { "Error: Comma not followed by an integer." }`. The way to solve any complex programming task is to break it into pieces and write functions to solve the individual pieces. You can simply that further by realising that substr defaults to the rest of the string if the second argument is omitted. So `userInput.substr(breakPoint + 1)` is all you need.

Comment: BTW the whole task would become considerably easier, and the code would become signifcantly more robust if you were to use the C++ regular expression library.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a convertor from std::string to integer. There are a few ways to do it in C++ but I think using of stoi function will cover all your cases (beware that stoi throws an exception if you try convert a string which is not an integer)

Here is a small example how to implement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string /* error string */ SplitLine(const std::string& inLine, std::string& outString, int& outNumber)
{
    const std::string separator = ",";
    auto pos = inLine.find(separator);
    auto pos2 = inLine.rfind(separator);

    if (pos == std::string::npos) {
        return "No comma in string.";
    }

    if (pos != pos2 && pos2 != std::string::npos) {
        return "Too many commas in input.";
    }

    outString = inLine.substr(0, pos);
    std::string remain_part = inLine.substr(pos+1);
    try {
        outNumber = stoi(remain_part);
    }
    catch (...) {
        return "Comma not followed by an integer.";
    }

    return "";
}

void ProcessLine(const std::string& inLine)
{
    std::string result;
    int num = 0;
    auto error = SplitLine(inLine, result, num);

    if (!error.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Data string: " << result << " Data integer: " << num << std::endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    ProcessLine("Ernest Hemingway 9");
    ProcessLine("Ernest, Hemingway, 9");
    ProcessLine("Ernest Hemingway, nine");
    ProcessLine("Ernest Hemingway, 9");

    return 0;
}
```